# slogan and background image attach responsively

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I am trying to design such header where the slogan and background image are attached in the stated picture. I want to use flex to make it work but it is not working. Giving width breaks the responsiveness. I have created a jsbin to show the demo and here it is

http://jsbin.com/muguwavosa/edit?html,css,output

The source code

```css
    .header {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      background-image: url('https://www.rj-investments.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Home-Featured.jpg');
      background-size: cover;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center center;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      padding: 100px 0;
    }
    
    .slogan-wrapper {
      background: #fff;
      padding: 80px 0 0 40px;
      margin-top: 70px;
    }
    
    .slogan-text > h1 {
      font-size: 3.375rem;
      font-weight: 900;
      letter-spacing: 5px;
      color: #373f48;
    }
    
    .slogan-text {
      padding: 100px 70px 100px 0;
      position: relative;
      background: #fff;
      z-index: 1;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="header">
      <div class="slogan-wrapper grid">
        <div class="slogan">
          <div class="slogan-text">
            <h1>Hustle, Loyalty, Respect</h1>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is what I wanted exactly and its a full width header

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice that the class 'span' div is closed with a p tag? If you wanted to put the width there then that would be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change the below code in CSS file and try once.

```
.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-image: url('https://www.rj-investments.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Home-Featured.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  padding: 100px 0;
}

.slogan-wrapper {
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.slogan-text > h1 {
      font-size: 3.375rem;
    font-weight: 900;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    color: #373f48;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 80px 40px;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 319px;
}

.slogan-text {
  padding: 100px 30px 100px 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```